# jQuery doesn't display background image

Tags: php, jquery

I have a newbie question.

I am trying to display a background-image for an a-element. On mouseover the picture should change to different picture.
The problem is that the pictures are not being displayed. When I had the code in CSS it worked fine so it must be my function that makes problems.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".person").css({background-image: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/person.jpg')});
        $(".person").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css({background-image: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/person-hover.jpg')});    
        });      
    });
    var body = $( 'body' );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="silhoulettes">
    <a class="person" href="<?php echo get_permalink(41); ?>"></a>
</div>
```

There are some php wordpress functions between.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is the PHP part processed at least (needs to be set inside a PHP file)? Check in browser what URL you get

Comment: So have you checked what the result is of `get_stylesheet_directory_url()`,  and have you verified that the resulting url is correct?

Comment: Not related to the question, but to make thinks neater you can use shorthand php tags within HTML. `<?=get_permalink(41);?>`

Comment: You've need to put quotes around the value you're setting in the `css()` method. Check the console as you've probably got a syntax error

Comment: Yes, the url was correct.
scottevans93  - thank you, very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The correct way of giving css via jQuery is `css("propertyname","value");` and `css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});` for multiple style.

Try this

```
$(".person").css({"background-image"," url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>'/img/person.jpg")});
$(".person").mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css({"background-image", "url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>'/img/person-hover.jpg")});    
 });
```

**Changes Made**

```
$(".person").css({background-image: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/person.jpg')});
```

**to**

```
$(".person").css({"background-image"," url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>'/img/person.jpg")});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got an error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

I've read that I can use css in jquery like this to combine elements together:
`$('p').css({color:green,font-size:14px});`

Comment: It works! You've made some mistakes with apostrophes. Thank you. Could you please comment on this part: `$('p').css({color:green,font-size:14px});`. Is it correct with jQuery?

Comment: Can you let me know where I can change the apostrophes ? So that I can improve my answer.

Comment: after the url in the brackets there shoud be `'` instead of `"`, and after that closing bracket there should be `"`

Comment: @Dandy You have made a mistake. `"`is necessary while adding css

Answer (score 0):

Try below syntax

```
var imgUrl = '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/person.jpg';

$(".person").css("background-image","url("+ imgUrl +")");
```